# Why is it considered incorrect to use the variable of integration as a boundary of integration?

Tags: calculus, limits, integration

Recently, a question was asked about limits of integration and the OP made the following "typo":
$$I =  \int_0^x f(x) \, dx$$
as opposed to
$$I =  \int_0^x f(t) \, dt $$
I commented that this typically frowned upon and can make for some odd results. It occured to me however, that I wasn't sure why this was formally incorrect, but that I had just been taught that it shouldn't be done. I couldn't think of a reason why it's considered best practices to differentiate between variable of integration and variables in the limits of integration..

Any thoughts / reasoning behind this?

Comment: That is because the variable of integration and the boundary are two different things, thus, using the same symbol for both might lead to mistakes.

Comment: In other words, it is not wrong, just *very* confusing,

Comment: Your $I$ depends on $x$, soit's really an $I(x)$. But the real problems arise when you have $\int_0^x f(x,t)\,\mathrm dt$ and decide to use only one variable instead of two.

Comment: The concept of definite integration involves a function defined on a closed interval and is a real number normally. In case you make the end points of interval variable (say a function of $x$) then your entire integral is a function of $x$. The variable of integration (i.e. the $x$ in $dx$) has no significance in definite integration. It is only for symbolic convenience (like say during substitution). You may just write $\int_{0}^{x}f$. Even the $f$ can be written without $x$ provided you have defined $f$ somewhere.

Comment: just to add to the previous comment, normally we replace the function $f$ by their actual expressions (say $x^{2}$) and in this case we need some variable to represent $f$ and then it makes sense to keep the variable used for $f$ as different from that used for the limits of integration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's consider a simple case:
$\int_0^x x\; dx$.

Applying the usual method,
$\int_0^x x\; dx
= \dfrac{x^2}{2}\big|_0^x
=\text{?}
$

The lower term is
$\dfrac{x^2}{2}$
evaluated at $x=0$,
and this is obviously $0$.

The upper term is
more problematical.
It is
$\dfrac{x^2}{2}$
evaluated at $x=x$,
and it is unclear what this means.

Suppose the integral was
$\int_0^{2x} x\; dx$.
The upper term would then be
$\dfrac{x^2}{2}$
evaluated at $x=2x$,
and it is even more unclear what this means.

Good notation makes ideas clear
and helps avoid mistakes;
as shown here,
using the same variable for
the variable of integration
and a limit of integration
can make things unclear.

Comment: It is not at all unclear to me what $\int_0^{2x} x\,dx$ means. It means to take the antiderivative of $x$ and then substitute $2x$ everywhere there is an $x$. There is no equation between $x$ and $2x$, just a symbolic replacement.

Comment: @CarlMummert Rather than an equation, I believe we could use the symbol $\mapsto$ to avoid confusion:  "The upper term would then be $\frac {x^2}2$ evaluated at $x\mapsto x[\cdots]$". I believe this is much clearer in meaning

Answer (score 3):

Let's think about this for a second.  What is

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x dx \, f(x)$$

Oh! Did you mean

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x dt \, f(t)$$

I hope you see why the former is nonsense.

Comment: What is $dx\,f(x)$? I haven't downvoted but I have no idea what is being said.

Comment: @CarlMummert: not that you have asked $n$ times, but as a whole I have answered this more times than I can count - it is simply the definite integral $\int_0^x f(t) dt$; I am used to writing it this way from 20 years or so of physics.

Comment: @CarlMummert Some people put the $dx$ of an integral inside the integrand instead of outside. It's just notation.

Comment: @Potato: many thanks!

Comment: I don't see why $\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x f(x)\,dx$ is nonsense.

Comment: @CarlMummert: I don't see why it isn't, at least within the confines of beginning calculus.  Please enlighten me.

Comment: I expanded my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If someone were to write a function:

$$g(x) = \int_0^x f(x,t)dt$$

it becomes clearer why this is problematic. If you instead wrote:

$$g(x)=\int_0^x f(x,x)dx$$

then which $x$ is constant inside the integral, and which $x$ is not?

The same problem happens if you are using $\Sigma$ expressions for sums:

$$\sum_{n=1}^n g(n)$$
is unclear. This could be interpreted either as $ng(n)$ or as $g(1)+g(2)+\dots+g(n)$.

Comment: This issue also disappears as soon as we identify the function is being integrated. In this case, $f(x,t)$ is intended to be a function of two variables, so we can't just "integrate from 0 to $x$" as if $f$ was a one-dimensional function. In particular $\int_0^x f(x,x)\,dx$ is an integral along the diagonal of a certain square, while $\int_0^x f(x,t)\,dt$ represents an integral on a path with a fixed $x$ value.

Comment: I'm missing your point - $\int_0^x f(x,x)dx$ is ambiguous - it doesn't *mean* anything. It could mean, $\int f(x,t)dt$ of $\int f(t,t)dt$ or $\int f(x,x)dt$. @CarlMummert

Comment: Say $f$ is defined on the real plane. Then $\int_0^x f(x,x)\,dx$, for any fixed $x$, is the same gemometric integral as $\int_\gamma f(\gamma)\,ds$ where $\gamma$ is the linear path from $(0,0)$ to $(x,x)$.

Comment: That's certainly one way to interpret it, but it is not clear that is what is meant - the expression is ambiguous. This interpretation is not definitive. @CarlMummert

Comment: The key point is that the integral $\int_a^b f(t)\,dt$ in Calculus 1, is defined for real numbers $a$ and $b$ and a function $f$ of one real variable. It is not defined for an expression $f$ or for a function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$. So $\int_0^x xt\,dt$ is equally ambiguous from the point of view of the definition - we have to figure out which function $g(t)$ defined on a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is actually being integrated.

Comment: So, for $H\colon \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, $H(x,x)$ is a one-variable function $f$ (it is the composition $H \circ D$ where $D\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is given by $D(x) = (x,x)$). Then $\int_0^x H(x,x)\,dx$, where $x$ is fixed, is just the definite integral of that one-variable function on the interval $[0,x]$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that (as I wrote in [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/446638/630) just now) calculus books do not tend to distinguish between the integral of a function and the integral of an expression.

Let's look first at $\int_0^{2x} x\,dx$.

- One option is to interpret this as the integral of the function $f(x) = x$ on an interval from $0$ to $2x$. There is nothing odd about that. For any fixed $x$, $\int_{[0,2x]} f$ will be equal to $2x^2$. The "x" inside the integral has no effect because we just view the $x\,dx$ as telling us what function is being integrated, and the function itself is a set that doesn't know anything about "x".
- Another option is to view "$\int_0^{2x} x\,dx$" purely as a symbolic expression and apply a fixed algorithm to it. In this case, that algorithm is to use a table to look up the integral of $x$, which is $x^2/2$, and then substitute the limits to get $(2x)^2/2 - (0)^2/2$, which simplifies to $2x^2$.

Similarly, we can look at 
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x f(x)\, dx,$$
where $f$ is continuous. In this case $\int_0^x f(x)\,dx$ is some antiderivative $F(x)$ of $f$, and $\frac{d}{dx} F(x)$ is then just $f(x)$ again. There is no conflict if we view $f(x)$ as a function. The only source of confusion is that calculus books often fail to include  complete rules for how to handle derivatives like that as expressions. For example, most books do not indicate that the rule $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xf(t)\,dt = f(x)$ cannot be blindly applied to the expression $f(t) = xt$. But that only because the books tend to take a functional approach rather than expression-based one.

In neither case is there any problem with the variable of integration being the same as the limit of integration. The same phenomenon holds in general: if we view the integral as operating on a *function* then the use of any variable in the integrand becomes meaningless once we identify the specific function being integrated, while if we view the integral symbolically and know the correct formal rules to follow then there is again no issue.

Comment: If I get the the nub of what you are saying, it is that definite integration consists of two separate steps: computing the primitive, and then evaluating the primitive at upper and lower limits.  Fine.  But that is not how we express it; rather, we express the definite integral as a single entity, and the use of the same symbol for dummy variable and limit serves to confuse.

The point I am making is that the symbols have meaning as written.  $x$ antiderivative here is taken to mean the same thing as $x$ limit.  To differentiate them, you need to provide different contexts.

Comment: @Ron Gordon: the situation is even more clear when we look at the definition of the definite integral, which takes fixed real numbers $a,b$ and a fixed function $f\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$. That function $f$ is just a function - a set of ordered pairs. To directly apply the definition to something like $\int_0^x x^2\,dx$ we have assume that the limits represent fixed real numbers $0$ and $x$, and we have to identify the function (it is the function $\lambda x . x^2$). After that, the answer is just a particular real number.

Comment: Carl, totally not disagreeing with you here with respect to advanced users.  But for people on the level of learning the Fundamental Theorem, it simply doesn't work for learning and is terrible practice.  When I inspected a colleague's work, nine times out of ten when presented with an integral as you have written, it pointed to errors in understanding the mathematics (and sloppy work in general).  So I think our disagreement is in appropriateness of the notation - I think such notation should never be shown to a beginner, because it looks like nonsense.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to what Marty said i think the latter integral (too lazy to type!) is considered wrong mainly because the limits of integration are a function of x as well.
A big contradiction to the equality of former integral and latter integral is when you differentiate the integral.
 
Just try that thing out in both the cases we get totally different answers.
 
latter integral is a f(x,t) which has a different and more complicated differentiating form.

There might be many more reasons to this but yeah you should get the idea.

If however the limits are independent of x then you can always do that x --> t shift .